# Linq to Entities - Internal Behavior of Skip and Take

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a question about the internal behavior of Skip and Take. Do subsequent calls to skip and take move an internal pointer forward?

So, in other words, is:

```
var rowset = entities.ActivityRecords
                    .Where(ar => ar.State == (int)LineItemStates.Created 
                        && ar.Timestamp >= cycleIteration.StartDate //within the date range
                        && ar.Timestamp <= cycleIteration.EndDate 
                        && matchingProducts.Contains(ar.ProductId))
                    .OrderBy(ar2 => ar2.Id);

rowset.Skip(10); //only works if we're consuming an iterator and the pointer is moving forward. Does this move an internal pointer forward?
return rowset.Take(10);
```

equivalent to:

```
var rowset = entities.ActivityRecords
                    .Where(ar => ar.State == (int)LineItemStates.Created 
                        && ar.Timestamp >= cycleIteration.StartDate //within the date range
                        && ar.Timestamp <= cycleIteration.EndDate 
                        && matchingProducts.Contains(ar.ProductId))
                    .OrderBy(ar2 => ar2.Id);

return rowset.Skip(10).Take(10);
```

I have a bug I'm investigating, and I believe the problem is that the r.Take(x) is in a loop where the intent is to keep taking `x` rows with each loop execution and thus consume the entire set, but I'm guessing the latter code snippet is required over the former as I don't think Skip and Take are really moving any internal pointer iterator forward.

Comment: An internal pointer in generated sql?  That would be quite interesting :) .  Make sure not to confuse EF Linq with Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: Also, `rowset.Skip(10)` does nothing since the value isn't returned and reassigned.  It would need to be `rowset = rowset.Skip(10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `rowSet.Take(x)` is in a loop where the intent is to keep taking x rows with each loop execution and thus consume the entire set

You are right, this bug is caused by a misunderstanding. You cannot repeatedly call `Take` on the same `rowSet` and expect different results. Since the query is evaluated lazily, each call would get you the same ten rows again and again, and your loop would not stop.

Comment: So does a call to entities.SaveChanges() between iterations of rowset.Take(x) change anything? The rows are being mutated in a way that will cause them to no longer appear in subsequent queries. Is rowset.Take(x) re-evaluated with a new SQL query every time? Otherwise, I don't understand why we haven't been seeing infinite loop behavior prior to this.

Comment: @user497745 If you mutate and save changes so that the processed rows are no longer in the result set in between of calling `Take(x)`, then indeed you would not see an infinite loop. `IQueryable<T>` sends a new query to RDBMS each time you enumerate it, so rows that are no longer eligible are not returned.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the assistance.